# mysql update foreign keys in child table

Tags: mysql

When trying to build my database (data is filled in automaticly with python). I noticed that the foreign keys I had set up, were all null.
After searching I learned that I needed to insert/update them.
but when using UPDATE, it doesn't find the PK of the one that needed to be linked. Can't I use update?

This is the table with all the foreign keys:

```
+---------------+--------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-------+---------+------------+-------+
| sequencing_id | run_id | reagent_id | quant_id | pool_id | sample_id | batch_name   | cluster_density | Q30   | phasing | prephasing | pf    |
+---------------+--------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-------+---------+------------+-------+
|             1 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200220 |          256465 | 92.48 | 0.00181 |    0.00122 |  87.4 |
|             2 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200221 |          260639 | 92.47 |  0.0018 |     0.0011 | 86.84 |
|             3 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200224 |          250063 |  92.9 | 0.00179 |    0.00111 | 87.75 |
|             4 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200225 |          248809 |  92.5 | 0.00186 |     0.0012 |    88 |
|             5 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200226 |          243767 | 93.24 | 0.00181 |    0.00121 | 88.89 |
|             6 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200227 |          236970 | 93.31 | 0.00173 |    0.00116 | 89.09 |
|             7 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200228 |          246834 | 93.05 | 0.00171 |    0.00113 | 88.48 |
|             8 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200302 |          258406 | 92.33 | 0.00183 |    0.00123 | 87.19 |
|             9 |   NULL |       NULL |     NULL |    NULL |      NULL | NIPT20200304 |          268314 | 92.34 | 0.00181 |    0.00102 | 86.37 |
+---------------+--------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-------+---------+------------+-------+
```

And this is how I'm trying to update (for example) the quant_id and the error I get:

```
MariaDB [nipt]> update sequencing_report set quant_id = quant_report.quant_id ;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'quant_report.quant_id' in 'field list'
```

The table referencing also has the `batch_name` column

edit:
added other table and the pk, fk conditions:

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| quant_id | batch_name   | std_rsquared | std_slope  | median_pg_�l |
+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
|        1 | NIPT20200220 | 0.9995104    | 1.03670669 |       48.131 |
|        2 | NIPT20200221 | 0.9997006    | 1.03217947 |      47.8605 |
|        3 | NIPT20200224 | 0.999357641  | 1.04794788 |      49.9383 |
|        4 | NIPT20200225 | 0.9997197    | 1.03864324 |       49.729 |
|        5 | NIPT20200226 | 0.9994419    | 1.05751264 |      45.4662 |
|        6 | NIPT20200227 | 0.9985618    | 1.046124   |      48.1163 |
|        7 | NIPT20200228 | 0.999746561  | 1.03478575 |      50.5826 |
|        8 | NIPT20200302 | 0.999785841  | 1.031522   |       47.843 |
|        9 | NIPT20200304 | 0.9996195    | 1.05977166 |      47.7563 |
+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
quant_report PK and FK:      
UNIQUE INDEX `batch_name_UNIQUE` (`batch_name` ASC) VISIBLE,
      PRIMARY KEY (`quant_id`),
      INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`quant_id` ASC) VISIBLE)

sequencing_report PK and FK:
  INDEX `fk_reagent_idx` (`reagent_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_quant_idx` (`quant_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_pool_idx` (`pool_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_sample_idx` (`sample_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sequencing_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `sequencing_id_UNIQUE` (`sequencing_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_run`
    FOREIGN KEY (`run_id`)
    REFERENCES `nipt`.`run_parameters` (`run_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reagent`
    FOREIGN KEY (`reagent_id`)
    REFERENCES `nipt`.`reagent_report` (`reagent_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_quant`
    FOREIGN KEY (`quant_id`)
    REFERENCES `nipt`.`quant_report` (`quant_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pool`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pool_id`)
    REFERENCES `nipt`.`pool_report` (`pool_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sample`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sample_id`)
    REFERENCES `nipt`.`sample_report` (`sample_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: Can you show the second table and also the primary and foreign key definitions.

Comment: I have a database with multiple tables set up in a star schema.  the table with all the FK is 'sequencing_report' and trying to update the quant_id from the "quant_report". This needs to be done for the other tables aswell. but when knowing one, I can do the rest

Comment: You appear to be looking for multi table update see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html for syntax and examples.